# How to keep Spinner's Selected values after restarting application

Tags: android, spinner

the question is quite obvious but still nothing worked for me. In my application i'm selecting value from spinner and wanna to let spinner to show selected value after restarting application. to store spinner value i'm using `shared preferences` But when restarts application logcat shows `null pointer error`. Here's code

```
String options[]={"-Select-", "Domino's","Pizza Hut", "Pizza Bite"}; 
Spinner spin;
int formatposition;
fSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.fSpinner);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String> (MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,options);
            fSpinner.setAdapter(adp);
```

To store spinner selected value:

```
Editor editee = preferences.edit();
                    editee.putInt("lastindex", spin.getSelectedItemPosition());
                    editee.commit();
```

To restore shared preferences when application restarts

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)                  //onCreate is called when the activity is starting
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    context=this;
    listViewSMS=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvSMS);                                 //view that shows items in a vertically scrolling list
    btnaddnew = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaddnew);
    btnaddnew.setOnClickListener(this);
   formatposition = preferences.getInt("lastindex", 0);
    spin.setSelection(formatposition);
}
```

Comment: **WHEN** do you call `spin.setSelection(spinposition);`?

Comment: @Der Golem in onCreate method

Comment: NO. I want to know WHEN EXACTLY do you call it. Show me your onCreate code

Comment: @Der Golem check my edits for onCreate method

Comment: And WHEN do you call `fSpinner.setAdapter(adp);`?

Comment: @Der Golem calls spin.setAdapter(adp) in onClick button method which opens dialog box that contain Spinner spin

Comment: So, you see the point where I wanted you. You fill the spinner **AFTER** you try to set its position. How can you set the position, when the spinner **is empty**?

Comment: @Der Golem so what's the solution for this

Comment: Fill the spinner in your onCreate and call this `spin.setSelection(formatposition);` after this `fSpinner.setAdapter(adp);`

Answer (score 0):

```
How could array find index without name of array??
```

Try this one to solve:-

```
   spinposition = preferences.getInt("lastindex", 0);
   spin.setSelection(spinposition);
```

Comment: showing error: The method setSelection(int) in the type AbsSpinner is not applicable for the arguments (String)